# How can i find gradient input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient

How can i find log likilihood layer if i have:

```
logP = [[-5.8971105e+00 -1.3536860e-01 -2.3225722e+00 -3.6559267e+00]
        [-7.1035299e+00 -7.1037712e+00 -8.0828800e+00 -1.9549085e-03]]
oneHotTruth = [[0. 0. 0. 1.]
               [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

gradInput should be equal:

```
[[ 0.   0.   0.  -0.5]
 [ 0.   0.   0.  -0.5]]
```

Need to implement without using the library pytorch / tf

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `a-log` and `y-one-hot`, Did you meant the variables? It seems you are doing binary classification. Your task and your assumption about noise will impact your result.

Comment: I need to solve a problem in which it is necessary to find the input gradient using the input data. Edits accepted